# Pushing jsoup elements into a database

Tags: java, jdbc, jsoup

I'm using the Jsoup HTML parser to get information from a particular website, in my case the name of a product and the price of the product.

After fetching the above mentioned I have two different array lists of product names and their equivalent prices.

Now, I have to put them both in a database table as a pair of course, but this is where I'm getting stuck. Is there a way to solve this?

Here's the snippet below...

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.winwin.rs/").timeout(6000).get();

Elements names = document.getElementsByClass("product-name");
Elements prices = document.getElementsByClass("price");

String query = "insert into product (name, price) values (?, ?)";
Connection conn = mysqlconnect.ConnectDb();
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

for (Element element : names) {
    preparedStmt.setString(1, element.text()); 
}

for (Element element : prices) {
    preparedStmt.setString(2, element.text()); 
}

preparedStmt.execute();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lists have the same length and the order of product names and price is valid, you can use a classic for loop. And I would recomend to use batch update instead of inserting the product details one by one. Example

```
Elements names = document.getElementsByClass("product-name");
Elements prices = document.getElementsByClass("price");

String query = " insert into product (name,price) values (?,?)";
Connection conn = mysqlconnect.ConnectDb();
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

conn.setAutoCommit(false);  
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
     preparedStmt.setString(1,names.get(i).text()); 
     preparedStmt.setString(2,prices.get(i).text()); 
     preparedStmt.addBatch();
}
preparedStmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

Comment: Okay, but where do you loop through prices arraylist in your code?